# How do I turn display on or off on a class with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to display a table with each row having a different class.

```
<table>
<tr class="blue"><td></td></tr>
<tr class="red"><td></td></tr>
<tr class="green"><td></td></tr></table>
```

What I'm trying to do is have a user select a radio button and using jquery, it will display either blue, green, red or all rows depending on what's selected. How do I do this?

Comment: Trigger the event on the radio then add/remove a _special_ class (hidden, for example).

Comment: Use `$.hide()` and `$.show()` with class selectors in your radio buttons' click handler.

Comment: Thanks guys. I took care of it with class selectors.

Answer (score 0):

While doing it in this manner may not be the easiest approach (you could just change the class of that tr, you will need to query that particular element, and simply set the style.display property to 'none'

i.e.

```
$('table','tr','.green').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: `$('table','tr','.green').hide();` has the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the HTML to be as

```
<input type="radio" name="color" value="blue">Blue
<input type="radio" name="color" value="red">Red
<input type="radio" name="color" value="green">Green
<table>
  <tr class="blue"><td>11111111</td></tr>
  <tr class="red"><td>22222222</td></tr>
  <tr class="green"><td>33333333</td></tr>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

The jquery code would be as

​

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='radio']").on("click", function(){
        var self = $(this);
        $("table tr").each(function(){
            if(!$(this).hasClass(self.val())){
                 $(this).hide();
            } else {
                 $(this).show();
            }                
        });


    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ufomammut66/SxuXY/

Basically we add a click event to any input with a name of color that looks at the value of the input and shows/hides accordingly.